# Getting post data from form with iframe doesn't work PHP

Tags: php

I have this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<iframe name="votar" style="display:none;"></iframe>
<form id="excel form" method="post" target="votar">
<input type="submit" name="test" id="test" value="RUN" /><br/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['test']))
{
   echo "hello world";
}
?>
```

what am I trying to do? well I try to get hte post data from this form without reloading the page and without using ajax, but what am I doing wrong? I tried looking around, but all the other solutions are to long or just not prectical for my website. please help.

EDIT

just changed submit to test, doesn't matter.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but I think, your idea is not possible. Because PHP is a Server Side language and at first it checks if `$_POST['test']` exisits. Then it renders the HTML. If you Submit the Iframe, the POST Request is send but the Frontpage never gets the new Data, because the Server has no option to re execute the PHP. But maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: remove `style="display:none;"` from <iframe>, your code is working but due to iframe is hide, it is not showing "hello world",

Comment: Form id with a space?

Answer (score 0):

```html
<form action="" method="post" >
 <!-- code -->
</form>
```